# What do PageStatusBar element do in the Master page?

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage

I am customizing our site's Master page. The Master page was developed by ex-employee so I am not starting from a clear Master page.

In the page a tab like below:

```
<div id="s4-statusbarcontainer">
  <div id="pageStatusBar" class="s4-status-s1"></div>
</div>
```

After some research I think the bar is for warning show up like "Checked out to you. Only you can see your recent changes. Check it in." However it is not true. When I render some page a new tab **DeltaPageStatusBar** will be added to the bottom of ribbon bar. The tab I mentioned above have no change at all.

Although I can get rid of it with CSS display:none but I am worry something will be hidden. Could you please give me some hints? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new versions of SharePoint the new masterpages often contains elements of the masterpages from the previous version of SharePoint to support upgraded sites so no functionality is lost.

This element is the legacy statusbar from SharePoint 2010. DeltaPageStatusBar is the one used in SharePoint 2013, making the legacy statusbar redundant. It causes no harm in being there - leave it be or remove it. Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

this container is for displaying status informations. And you are right with your research that also information about the page status (e.g. checked out or checked in) will displayed.
This is a system element of the Masterpage structure and I think required. In cause of this, it is not good or recommended to remove or rename the element.

SharePoint 2013 supports Minimal Download Strategy (MDS). This feature minimize the network traffic by loading only the delta of the current Page. This is the reason why you find so many Delta Controls in your Masterpage.

You can hide this control using CSS and the attribute dispaly:none. As your already mentioned! But then your users did not get informations about the status anymore. And i think this is not productiv, or am i wrong?

I hope i could help you. If not let me know :)